STM32 SPI communication with 93C46 EEPROM
I want to sent commands (Read, Write, etc.) to a 93C46 EEPROM with a STM32 micro-controller through the SPI interface. The data sheet of 93C46 says that we should send (e.g.) 20 clock cycles for a Write command (as you can see in the below picture), but I can not send this number of clocks with STM32. In STM32 I can just sent a multiple of 8 bits (clock cycles) with HAL functions. Do any one know how can I make a successful communicate with 93C46 E2PROM by a STM32?

Possibly you can just sent 24 bits, and hope that the chip ignores the extra 4 clocks - the datasheet doesn't seem to specify this, one way or the other.  Your other options would be to bit-bang the protocol, or to choose some EEPROM chip (such as the 25LC010) that actually uses standard SPI, rather than this abomination.

Your picture shows clearly how additional clock bis will be recognized. I assume it’s fin to use 24-bit frames. Also look at the implementation in the Linux kernel. It has SPI and bit-banging support. @jasonharper, isn’t it clear? It even has an explanation on the picture in question (keyword Glitch).

There is a library that you could take a look at how the sendCommand() is implemented.
